# How to find a point perpendicualr to two points

Tags: trigonometry

I have two points x1,y1 and x2,y2 how can i find a point perpendicular to these two points.

I tried using the midpoint formula but it did not work

Comment: what do you mean!? lines can be perpendicular but not points!

Comment: I suppose that you want a line perpendicular to the line passing throug the two points? Right?

Comment: What is the context of this question?

Comment: You want a perpendicular to the line, which passing through the two points ? This perpendicular has to go through the midpoint ?

Comment: Is this related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463914/how-to-find-the-mid-point-on-a-cirle-with-two-points?

Comment: I mean that when i move mouse i store the first point and the second point and than i use ((b.x ‐ a.x)*(c.y ‐ a.y) ‐ (b.y ‐ a.y)*(c.x ‐ a.x))   formula to find that if movement is clock wise or anti clockwise, here  a is the the mid point of these two points b and c.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant a line that is perpendicular to the line joining those 2 points. If so:

1. Calculate the gradient of the line joining those 2 points (m1)
2. Use m1.m2=-1 to find the gradient perpendicular to the line (m2)
3. Using the midpoint (x3,y3) that you have found earlier, use y-y3=m2(x-x3) to get the equation of the perpendicular line